# Renderizado del lado del servidor para el router de react con react-rails

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, server-side-rendering

Estoy tratando de configurar una aplicación de react-rails con renderizado del lado del servidor, el problema surge cuando trato de refactorizar el código para el router de react para que funcione con la opción de renderizado del lado del servidor activada.

```
<%= react_component("Main", {csrf_token: form_authenticity_token, post_cookie: @post_cookie, {prerender: true}) %>
```

Las rutas que supuestamente conducen a los componentes 'Comment' y 'Post' no son funcionales, ¿cómo podría hacer que funcionen?

```
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

function Main(props, railsContext) {

  const { location } = railsContext;
  const context = {};

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <StaticRouter location={location} context={context}>
        <Switch>
        {console.log("Context static router", context, context.url)}

          <Route exact path={"/"}>
            <PostsWrap post_cookie={props.post_cookie} />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path={"/:locale"}>
            <PostsWrap post_cookie={props.post_cookie} />
          </Route>

          <Route path={"/:locale/:user/posts/:post/:comment"} component={Comment} />

          <Route path={"/:locale/:user/:post"} component={Post} />
        </Switch>
      </StaticRouter>
  );
}

export default Main;
```